# Restore Windows 8 image to new drive without installation media

Tags: windows-8

I have created a Windows 8 image which is now stored on an external HDD.

My OS SSD died and I need to replace it. I no longer have the Windows installation disc. Is there a way to restore the image on the new SSD?

Comment: download the 90 day Enterprise Trial ISO, create a bootable USB flash drive and boot from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use another computer. Connect your external drive to it, and insert a large enough USB flash drive or DVD (a standard single-layer DVD should be fine, or a 4GB flash drive) into the computer, then download and install [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](http://wudt.codeplex.com/).

Run the Download Tool, select your Windows 8 ISO and click `Next`. Next you'll select either `USB device` or `DVD` depending on which media you prefer to use. When you've selected which type of media you want to use, you'll next have to select the actual device, which should appear in the dropdown menu. If it doesn't appear, hit refresh and look again. When you've selected the correct device, click `Begin copying` and it should start copying the ISO and make the USB flash drive or DVD bootable. After a bit of a wait, and assuming you don't encounter any errors, you should now be able to insert the flash drive or DVD into your computer and install Windows normally.